# Use the same provider for different login forms

Tags: php, symfony

In the application there are 2 login forms, one for clients and one for administrators.

The two forms use the same provider:

```
 security:
     providers:
        form_login:
            entity: { class: FMP\SecurityBundle\Entity\User, property: username }

 firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    app_secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            provider: form_login
            login_path: security_app_login
            check_path: security_app_login_check
            default_target_path: /
        logout:
            path: security_logout
            target: security_app_login

    admin_secured_area:
          pattern: ^/admin
          anonymous: ~
          form_login:
              provider: form_login
              login_path: security_admin_login
              check_path: security_admin_login_check
              default_target_path: /admin/
          logout:
              path: security_logout
              target: security_admin_login

    default:
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
```

DefaultController.php:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="security_app_login")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
     public function appLoginAction(Request $request)
     {
        return $this->loginAction($request, 'FMPSecurityBundle:Default:app_login.html.twig');
     }

     /**
      * @Route("/admin/login", name="security_admin_login")
      * @param Request $request
      * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
      */
      public function adminLoginAction(Request $request)
      {
           return $this->loginAction($request, 'FMPSecurityBundle:Default:admin_login.html.twig');
      }

      public function loginAction(Request $request, $template)
      {
          $session = $request->getSession();

          if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
              $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
          } else {
               $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
          }

          return $this->render($template, array(
              'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
              'error'         => $error,
          ));
      }

      /**
       * @Route("/login_check", name="security_app_login_check")
       */
      public function loginCheckAppAction()
      {
          //
      }

      /**
       * @Route("/admin/login_check", name="security_admin_login_check")
       */
      public function loginCheckAdminAction()
      {
          //
      }   

      /**
       * @Route("/logout", name="security_logout")
       */
      public function logoutAction()
      {
          //
      }
}
```

When I access the route `/admin/login` and log me in, the following error is returned:

> The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?

What is wrong? You can not use the same provider for different forms?

Comment: It's works for clients ?

Comment: @FrançoisDupont yes. It works for clients (/login) but not to administrators (/admin/login).

Comment: It's look like if you enter in this method : loginCheckAdminAction() but you didn't enter in the Symfony security system which check if you can access or not. Try to use the same check_path which is security_app_login_check

Comment: @FrançoisDupont It works if I use the same path (security_app_login_check), but if the user wrong fill the credentials, he is redirected to the client login page and not the administrator login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to swap you firewall configurations.

```
admin_secured_area:
      pattern: ^/admin
      anonymous: ~
      form_login:
          provider: form_login
          login_path: security_admin_login
          check_path: security_admin_login_check
          default_target_path: /admin/
      logout:
          path: security_logout
          target: security_admin_login

app_secured_area:
    pattern: ^/
    anonymous: ~
    form_login:
        provider: form_login
        login_path: security_app_login
        check_path: security_app_login_check
        default_target_path: /
    logout:
        path: security_logout
        target: security_app_login
```

In you configuration, always fires **app_secured_area** and never **admin_secured_area**

Comment: It worked! I do not understand, now works both forms. Why?

Comment: app_secured_area fires, because pattern ^/ matches for all request. So, admin_secured_area newer fires

Answer (score 1):

Then keep the same path to login check than clients because there is only one path to get the security system and add this to handle the redirection of your admin login

**EDIT** it's failure_path sorry

```
admin_secured_area:
      pattern: ^/admin
      anonymous: ~
      form_login:
          provider: form_login
          login_path: security_admin_login
          check_path: security_app_login_check
          failure_path: security_admin_login <----- ADD THIS LINE
          default_target_path: /admin/
      logout:
          path: security_logout
          target: security_admin_login
```

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]                     
  Unrecognized option "access_denied_url" under "security.firewalls.admin_secured_area.form_login"

Comment: It's not working, the administrator continues to be redirected to the client login page when the "bad credentials" error occurs.

Comment: Are you sure than when you goes on admin/login you are not redirect to /login ? If yes, swap your firewalls

Comment: I changed the order of my firewalls and now works.  I do not understand, now works both forms. Why?

Comment: Because when you try to access /admin/login the firewall  app_secured_area with pattern: ^/ is called before the admin firewall. Firewalls are called in the order in which they are defined. If the pattern didn't match Symfony will try the next pattern etc...